Opining on, and making a case for additional classes of data dumps
The data dumps traditionally were primarily meant as an insurance policy against the company going rogue.
Considering that the company 'now' sees the dumps as something they can turn into a product, and partially inspired by several conversations we've had I wonder if 'other' kinds of dumps other than post and comment dumps makes sense, both as potential addons to what SE's trying to productize and as further community insurance.
SE gets a reasonable amount of spam - and very co-incidentally, our system neatly categorises spam, and rude/offensive posts. The former would be useful in training spam filters (we already have smokey, but that works very informally) and the latter in examples of toxic language. Critically - its mostly classified fairly accurately by humans. For 'internal' SE use, or for tools that do things smokey does, it'll give a bigger, easy to search corpus of data including everything that ever got flagged.
Likewise - While there's been a spate of backend work (yay!) chat's been somewhat neglected. There's no 'proper' API for it, but there's times where it might be useful for the community to analyse historic chatroom events, either as an aggregate or cause its a record of a former comment thread.
Once again - these are default public, very organic interactions. I recall back in the day, Shog occasionally pulled some very entertaining statistics about chat usage, and having some way to archive these without scraping every page would be handy.
I'm not 'entirely' sure what's the best way to this (by parent site? By chat server?) but I suspect the community would find uses for this. Most of it is 'public' anyway, but considering these gen AI companies have a voracious appetite for anything it might potentially be sellable.
Could a spam dump, and a chat dump be considered in future?

just a question: to whose profit? Personally I don't even get how people are still willing to operate Smokey to sanitize their LLM train data for free. Now if I get your question correctly you would want the users to also produce other dumps to their benefit since "we will already be cooking our own dumps now that they stopped, we may as well go the extra mile"?? What's next, an users PII dump?

Primarily us - It'd let us keep access to chat logs should the worst happen, and the spam dump might be useful for folks building better spam reduction tools.  I don't as much need to tell people what cool stuff they can do, than make a case for these tools. But I don't think 'the community can build cool stuff' alone's got as much weight as it should.

"should the worst happen" - did someone post&delete another Tavern message that leaked a new master plan?

Not yet, no. But there's occationally a little anxiety over the future of chat. There's a lot of site history on chat and knowing its safe somewhere would be nice.
